# Profiling Hadoop Reduce tasks using hprof

Tags: java, hadoop, hprof

I'm trying to profile reduce tasks on a cluster using

```
conf.setBoolean("mapred.task.profile", true);
conf.set("mapred.task.profile.params", "-agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples,heap=sites,depth=6,force=n,thread=y,verbose=n,file=%s");
conf.set("mapred.task.profile.maps", "0-1");
conf.set("mapred.task.profile.reduces", "0-1");
```

As expected, I've got 4 profile files generated:

```
     2849 Mar 25 15:30 attempt_201402231438_11879_m_000000_0.profile
  8786788 Mar 25 15:30 attempt_201402231438_11879_m_000001_0.profile
  4129237 Mar 25 15:31 attempt_201402231438_11879_r_000000_0.profile
 12644892 Mar 25 15:32 attempt_201402231438_11879_r_000001_0.profile
```

(files with `_m_` are generated during mapper task profiling, and `_r_` are generated during reduce task profiling)

`attempt_201402231438_11879_m_000001_0.profile` looks good:

```
THREAD START (obj=50000161, id = 200001, name="main", group="main")
THREAD START (obj=500021bd, id = 200004, name="TGT Renewer for yampolsy", group="main")
THREAD END (id = 200004)
...
TRACE 300000: (thread=200001)
        <empty>
TRACE 300001: (thread=200001)
        java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:493)
TRACE 300002: (thread=200001)
        java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:206)
...
SITES BEGIN (ordered by live bytes) Tue Mar 25 15:30:45 2014
          percent          live          alloc'ed  stack class
 rank   self  accum     bytes objs     bytes  objs trace name
    1 35.41% 35.41%  99614736    1  99614736     1 317704 byte[]
    2 16.79% 52.20%  47232000 2880 125952000  7680 318394 char[]
...
SITES END
CPU SAMPLES BEGIN (total = 6089) Tue Mar 25 15:30:45 2014
rank   self  accum   count trace method
...
 859  0.02% 99.57%       1 319489 java.lang.System.arraycopy
 860  0.02% 99.59%       1 319490 java.lang.Object.<init>
CPU SAMPLES END
```

After that miracle starts:

1. `attempt_201402231438_11879_m_000000_0.profile` contains only standard header (no profile information). I'm not concerned about this file much as my primary interest is reducer, but this does not feel right
2. `attempt_201402231438_11879_r_000000_0.profile` and `attempt_201402231438_11879_r_000001_0.profile` contain thread and trace information, but does not include *CPU SAMPLES* and *SITES* information.

Job completed successfully.

Any idea what could go wrong?

Why I'm not getting *CPU SAMPLES* for reducers?

Did anyone experience the same problem?

Comment: Did you figure something out finally? I have a similar problem but in my case I debug just mappers and there is no CPU SAMPLES anywhere! For more info look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983999/hadoop-hprof-profiling-no-cpu-samples-written

Comment: I do not think so, I would update the post