# Hadoop HPROF profiling no CPU SAMPLES written

Tags: java, hadoop, profiling, hprof

I want to use HPROF to profile my Hadoop job. The problem is that I get `TRACES` but there is no `CPU SAMPLES` in the `profile.out` file. The code that I am using inside my run method is:

```
    /** Get configuration */
    Configuration conf = getConf();
    conf.set("textinputformat.record.delimiter","\n\n");
    conf.setStrings("args", args);

    /** JVM PROFILING */
    conf.setBoolean("mapreduce.task.profile", true);
    conf.set("mapreduce.task.profile.params", "-agentlib:hprof=cpu=samples," +
       "heap=sites,depth=6,force=n,thread=y,verbose=n,file=%s");
    conf.set("mapreduce.task.profile.maps", "0-2");
    conf.set("mapreduce.task.profile.reduces", "");

    /** Job configuration */
    Job job = new Job(conf, "HadoopSearch");
    job.setJarByClass(Search.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

    /** Set Mapper and Reducer, use identity reducer*/
    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

    /** Set input and output formats */
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    /** Set input and output path */
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path("/user/niko/16M"));  
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(cmd.getOptionValue("output")));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);

    return 0;
```

How do I get the `CPU SAMPLES` to be written in the output?

I also have s trange error message on the `stderr` but I think it is not related, since it is present also when the profiling is set to false or the code for enabling profiling is commented out. The error is

```
 log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
 log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Answer (score 3):

Yarn (or MRv1) is killing the container just after your job finish.
The CPU Samples can't be wrote on your profiling file. In fact, your traces should be truncated also.

You have to add the following option (or the equivalent on your Hadoop version) :

```
yarn.nodemanager.sleep-delay-before-sigkill.ms = 30000
# No. of ms to wait between sending a SIGTERM and SIGKILL to a container

yarn.nodemanager.process-kill-wait.ms = 30000
# Max time to wait for a process to come up when trying to cleanup a container

mapreduce.tasktracker.tasks.sleeptimebeforesigkill = 30000
# Same en MRv1 ?
```

(30 sec seems to enough)

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5465, which is fixed in newer Hadoop versions.

So solutions seem to be:

- use settings mentioned in ALSimon's answer, OR
- upgrade to Hadoop >= 2.8.0